# OrderByDescending with multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to sort by `d.DateUpdated` but only when it's not DateTime.MinValue. If it's DateTime.MinValue then I would need it to be able to sort by `d.DateCreated`. It there a way to do this with in the following line of code?

```
return database.Table<Announcement>()
    .Where(i => i.GroupId == groupId)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateUpdated)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: A DateTime object cannot be null.  The default value is 1/1/01 so null is any date not 1/1/01.

Comment: Given you said in a comment to a now deleted answer "Actually DateUpdated is not going to be null." perhaps you might want to edit your question to more accurately reflect your actual situation and the code you are working with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might as well use `ThenBy` method

```
return database.Table<Announcement>()
    .Where(i => i.GroupId == groupId)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateUpdated)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.DateCreated)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
return database.Table<Announcement>()
    .Where(i => i.GroupId == groupId)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateUpdated == null ? d.DateCreated : d.DateUpdated)
    .ToListAsync();
```